# Using a Dictionary for multiple class instances - see if entry of class exists

Tags: c#, .net, class, dictionary

When I use a dictionary to "dynamically' make multiple instances of a class - how do I refer to multiple statements

*My context is below with an extended more specific version of the question in bold - sorry if it requires clarification, I'm working on the edge of my understanding with this. Also this is my first question posted so sorry if there is too much or too little detail - THANKS*

I am processing and analyzing data.

To process this effectively I want to split it up by project, with some other details added - Therefore I have chosen a class to store these

```
public class Project
{
    public bool Academic { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Equipment { get; set; }
    public List<string> User = new List<string>();
    public List<int> Hours = new List<int>();


    public Project(bool academic, string projectName, string equipment, List<string> user, List<int> hours)
    {
        Academic = academic;
        ProjectName = projectName;
        Equipment = equipment;
        User = user;
        hours = Hours;
    }
}
```

My planned approach is to make an instance for each new project (I don't know how many there will be for a given entry)

**So I am using the dictionary class to create new instances of the Project class. When I get to each data entry I want to see if the equipment variable from the data matches the equipment variable for any of my existing instances.

I have a loop where I am trying to test this - but can't see how to define an equipment variable from a given instance of project**

I have added further code snippets below
dictionary initialization

```
public Dictionary<string, Type> projectNames = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
```

The code below is where I use the dictionary to create the first instance and then want to be able to check if the equipment exists.

It checks if the header has been read from the file, then stores the positions of the important headers for future lines. (Note it is passed on row at a time).
Then if the header has been read but there are no instances of the headings class it creates an instance. Otherwise I want it to step through each instance to see my above question

```
internal void writeEntry(int length, int pos, string input, Processing formObject, int k)
    {
        Processing processing = formObject;

        if (processing.headingsRead == false)
        {
            findHeadingPostitons(processing.CurrentLine);
            processing.headingsRead = true;
            string x = processing.CurrentLine[headingPostitions.ProjectPosition];
        }

        else
        {
            if(processing.projectNames.Count==0)
            {          
                Type projectType = processing.projectNames[k.ToString()];
                object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(projectType);
                Project myproject = (Project)myInstance;
                myproject.ProjectName = processing.CurrentLine[headingPostitions.ProjectPosition];
                myproject.Equipment = processing.CurrentLine[headingPostitions.EquipmentPosition];                   
                myproject.Commercial = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(processing.CurrentLine[headingPostitions.CommercialPosition]));
                myproject.User.Add(processing.CurrentLine[headingPostitions.LaserUserPosition]);
                float hours = hoursCalc(processing);
                myproject.Hours.Add(hours);
            }

            else
            {

                for(int i =0;i< processing.projectNames.Count;i++)
                {
                    if(processing.projectNames[i.ToString()]==????)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Edit**
For those coming at the problem with a mindset of trying to use a dictionary to create dynamic variables - it isn't the way to do it for C# - a list of class instances will do the job! (see the solution below)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Too much detail may make a question difficult do read, understand and answer. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get a better idea on how to ask perfectly. It is an art. ;)

Comment: "So I am using the dictionary class to create new instances of the Project class." You need 2 things, one is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx and the other is this: http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern. If this comment helps whatsoever, send me a msg. What I mean is, you want to use generics to populate/query the list, but each data point in your "Project" object will need an IEquatable to make life simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some expansion on my muddled comment. The goal here is to query your Project object by making use of Generics. In order to build your list, it appears as if a form parameter is used, hence ".net designer builder pattern". I hope this helps!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace GamerInMvc.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {       
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Create a list of parts.
            List<Project> parts = new List<Project>();

            // Add parts to the list.
            parts.Add(new Project() { ProjectName = "crank arm", ProjectId = 1234 });
            parts.Add(new Project() { ProjectName = "chain ring", ProjectId = 1334 });
            parts.Add(new Project() { ProjectName = "regular seat", ProjectId = 1434 });
            parts.Add(new Project() { ProjectName = "banana seat", ProjectId = 1444 });
            parts.Add(new Project() { ProjectName = "cassette", ProjectId = 1534 });
            parts.Add(new Project() { ProjectName = "shift lever", ProjectId = 1634 }); ;

            // Write out the parts in the list. This will call the overridden ToString method
            // in the Part class.
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (Project aPart in parts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aPart);
            }


            // Check the list for part #1734. This calls the IEquatable.Equals method
            // of the Part class, which checks the PartId for equality.
            Console.WriteLine("\nContains: Project with Id=1734: {0}",
                parts.Contains(new Project { ProjectId = 1734, ProjectName = "" }));

            // Find items where name contains "seat".
            Console.WriteLine("\nFind: Project where name contains \"seat\": {0}",
                parts.Find(x => x.ProjectName.Contains("seat")));

            // Check if an item with Id 1444 exists.
            Console.WriteLine("\nExists: Project with Id=1444: {0}",
                parts.Exists(x => x.ProjectId == 1444));

        }

    }

    public class Project : IEquatable<Project>
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public bool Academic { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string Equipment { get; set; }
        public bool Commercial { get; set; }

        public List<string> User = new List<string>();
        public List<int> Hours = new List<int>();

        public Project()
        {
            //parameterless ctor for demo
        }

        public Project(bool academic, string projectName, string equipment, List<string> user, List<int> hours)
        {
            Academic = academic;
            ProjectName = projectName;
            Equipment = equipment;
            User = user;
            hours = Hours;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ID: " + ProjectId + "   Name: " + ProjectName;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            Project objAsPart = obj as Project;
            if (objAsPart == null) return false;
            else return Equals(objAsPart);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ProjectId;
        }
        public bool Equals(Project other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.ProjectId.Equals(other.ProjectId));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - it looks like this answers my question but I have been snowed down with other stuff and haven't had the chance to try implementing it yet - when I do I'll accept the answer

Comment: @T.Ward Hope it helps.

Comment: This did indeed help and after some more reading was how I solved the problem (with a slightly different implementation to suit my application). Thank You!